# Access tabpage Controls by tabpage name

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to access tabpage Controls in c# by tabpage name.

I have tried to access from tabpagehandler but I was unable to access.

```
if (item is TabControl)
{
     ((TabControl)item).Selected += new TabControlEventHandler(TabChangeHandler);

}



public void TabChangeHandler(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
 {
   foreach (Control c in e.TabPage.Controls)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("controls on form =patternmatch " + c.Name);
   }
 }
```

Comment: By previous one I am unable to solve my problem ,,,,,,,so I am taking different approach. to solve that problem

Comment: not yet,,,,,,,,I have to access that tabpage by clickevent on tabcontrol

Comment: tabchangehandler is working properly,,,,,,,as I am performing different actions there,,,,,,,,,,,but It has arguments like object and TabControlEventArgs  ,,,,,,,,,,,,by converting then to controls by (Control)sender or e.TabPage.Controls,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,I am unable to fetch Controls present in tabpage but I can fetch tabpagename by e.TabPage.Name ,,,,,,,,,so I am thinking of accessing controls by name

Comment: yes purpose is same but approach is different and no satisfactory answer in both

Comment: No, you can't because the tabpage is just a container, not a class. The controls are not members of a class but just elements in a Controls collection. These can be added or removed dynamically, so the compiler wouldn't be able the check the references..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
var tabPageControls = tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage1"].Controls;
```

Comment: :how we can get all controls present in that tabpage like textbox,buttons from tabpagename

Comment: `tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage1"].Controls`

Comment: can you look at this question it would be of great help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500100/accessing-tabpage-controls-from-tabpagehandler